# how to know if a query is succes or fail in node and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a little REST API with express and mongoose, and my problem is relatively simple:

I need to know the typeError to send an statusCode and message to the client. Example, well, if a query for username: John Doe is false, how i know it? Exist a typeError for not matching querys? Or it returns me an empty object instead?

Thanks, and sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code explains how to handle finding duplicates(or at least how I've done it). It's up to you to determine the functions you'll implement for each response and really which query you use. To answer your question though, mongo returns an empty object if there is no duplicate.

```
Model.findOne({ user_id: 'John Doe' }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {conole.log(err) // do something if there is an error}
        if (user) {
            // Do something here if a match is found
        } else {
            // Do something here if nothing is found. 
});
```